# How to add Earlystopper in Classifier Model

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, python-3.x

I have designed the following Binary Classifier Neural Network Model for a task. I want to add an early stopper to the model so that the model stops at an epoch where it has stopped learning significantly. How can I do that?

**Model**

```
X = badge1_data[['1','2','3','Score']] 
y = badge1_data['APR']

#Standardizing the Input Features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

#Train Test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3)

#Create Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, 
                  input_dim=4, 
                  kernel_initializer='normal', 
                  activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(2, 
                  kernel_initializer='normal', 
                  activation='relu'))
   
model.add(Dense(1, 
                  activation='sigmoid',
                  kernel_initializer='normal'))
    
#Compile Model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Fit Model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5000, validation_split = 0.3, verbose=0, batch_size=256)

#Make predictions and convert to binary value
pred_train = model.predict(X_train)
pred_test = model.predict(X_test)

#ROC AUC Score
print('Train AUC = {:}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_train,pred_train)))
print('Test AUC = {:}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_test,pred_test)))

#Accuracy
print('Train Accuracy = ',accuracy_score(y_train,pred_train.round()))
print('Test Accuracy = ',accuracy_score(y_test,pred_test.round()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Early stopping can be achieved with Keras callbacks.

```py
early_stop= tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3)

history = model.fit(X, y, callbacks=[early_stop])
```

`patience: Number of epochs with no improvement after which training will be stopped.`

To define the meaning of "*significant learning stopping*", you will have to try with the parameters of Callback. e.g.

*monitor="val_loss",  min_delta=0, patience=0, mode="auto", baseline=None,* etc.

[Keras_API](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/)